# gatsby require.resolve cant find module in createPage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm following the tutorial here https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/using-gatsby-without-graphql/ and I have my gatsby-node.js filled in.

My current directory structure is:

```
public
src
-pages
-templates
--program_group.js
static
gatsby-config.js
gatsby-node.js
```

inside my gatsby-node.js file I have

```
programGroups.forEach(program => {
      createPage({
        path: `/programs/${program}/`,
        component: require.resolve("src/templates/program_group.js"),
        context: { program },
      })
    })
```

and when I run `gatsby develop` it says, "Cannot find module 'src/templates/program_group.js'"

I've tried changing the path to ./src/..... and ../src/ and every combination. The documentation says it should be relative to the config file, which the above path is...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative paths using `path.resolve`. This should work:

```
const path = require(`path`); // import it outside the function


    programGroups.forEach(program => {
          createPage({
            path: `/programs/${program}/`,
            component: path.resolve("./src/templates/programGroup.js"),
            context: { program },
          })
        })
```

You can't underscore the templates due to naming issues to, that's another point to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

So, oddly, you cannot have underscores in the template file name. This should be fixed in the gatsby compiler.
Solution: don't use _ in your template names